# AspectJ 6 + Netbeans 7.0 error when compiling application

Tags: java, netbeans, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to use AspectJ's latest version with netbeans 7.0. What I did was basically download the .jar file and extract it. After editing build.xml here how it looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="TestApp" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project TestApp.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

<taskdef classpath="C:/Users/lorddoskias/Desktop/aspectj-1.6.11/lib/aspectjtools.jar"
     resource="org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties"/>

<target name="aspectj">
  <echo level="info">--- aspectj (start) ---</echo> 
  <iajc destDir="${build.classes.dir}">
      <inpath>
        <pathelement location="C:/Users/lorddoskias/Desktop/aspectj-1.6.11/lib/aspectjrt.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}" />
      </inpath>
 <sourceroots>
  <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
 </sourceroots>
 <classpath>
  <pathelement location="${javac.classpath}"/>
  <pathelement location="${j2ee.platform.classpath}"/>
 </classpath>
  </iajc>
  <echo level="info">LORDDOSKIAS BRUTAL TEST ---</echo>
</target>

<target name="-post-compile" depends="aspectj"></target>


</project>
```

After I try to compile my project here is what I get:

```
The type Map is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, String>
error at public Map<String, String> getParametersForStep(int workflowId, int workstepPos) {

Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0
error at Map<String, String> hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And a lot more like those.

My java version is:

```
1.6.0_26 SE
```

Is there somewhere a tutorial as to how to use AspectJ with Netbeans 7.0. This won't be used for an EE application but for a simple console-based SE application. Also I don't have JavaEE installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies not within aspectj; you're probably trying to compile Java5+ code on a 1.4 or older project.

In Netbeans, right click the name of the project and change source/binary format to JDK 1.5 or 1.6. From that step you can go on solving other issues.